# Not sure how to run the CAS (compare and swap) code snippet from Redis documentation page

Tags: redis, lua

I am trying to run the code from the redis [transactions](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) page. Specifically, this part:

```
WATCH zset
element = ZRANGE zset 0 0
MULTI
ZREM zset element
EXEC
```

If I try to do it from the cli, line by line, I get this:

```
localhost:6380> zadd set 1 a
(integer) 1
localhost:6380> WATCH zset
localhost:6380> element = ZRANGE zset 0 0
(error) ERR unknown command 'element'
OK
```

which probably means I'm doing something wrong? I remember working with lua about 9 years ago, so this doesn't really look like lua either to me.

How does someone run that snippet? Is it only some kind of pseudocode?

Comment: Other than Redis having a Lua API, how is this post related to Lua?

Comment: read the question again

Answer (score 1):

As [@Dinei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3136474/dinei) said, the example given is pseudocode.

Let's look at it (I added line numbers for us to refer to):

```
1 WATCH zset
2 element = ZRANGE zset 0 0
3 MULTI
4 ZREM zset element
5 EXEC
```

The point of the exercise is to solve the race condition that would occur if we only read the key (with `ZRANGE`, in line `2`), and then modify the key (with `ZREM` in line 4).  I assume you understand the problem if we didn't use the "CAS" semantics, so no need to get into it.

As pointed out, `redis-cli` just gives you the ability to run redis commands and see their replies, but not save values in variables, etc.

So the idea of the example is that in line `2`, we are "saving" the result of the "read" operation, into a pseudo-variable `element`.

Then, in line `4`, we are using that value in our "set" operation, and of course lines `1`, `3` and `5` are just the "CAS" commands to ensure there is no race condition.

Presumably the actual usage of such commands would be done from a redis client in a programming language that would allow us to save the return value of the `ZRANGE` and then use it later in the `ZREM` command.

But if you wanted to run it in `redis-cli`, you'd see this, where we pretend that our client-side code would have read and saved `"a"` that was returned from `zrange` and then passed that value to the `zrem` command:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 1 a
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> watch zset
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange zset 0 0
1) "a"
127.0.0.1:6379> multi
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> zrem zset a
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379> exec
1) (integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is some kind of pseudocode.

`redis-cli` only accepts Redis commands, it is not a full-fledged editor nor supports direct Lua scripting (neither variables like the `element` variable in the pseudocode).

> I remember working with lua about 9 years ago, so this doesn't really look like lua either to me.

This is not Lua, it is pseudocode. Actually, the Redis [Transactions](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) page you linked to does not refer to Lua at all <sub>(and that's why [@Piglet's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61260764/not-sure-how-to-run-the-cas-compare-and-swap-code-snippet-from-redis-documenta#comment108382048_61260764) in your post makes sense).</sub>

However, it is possible to execute Lua scripts by using Redis' [`EVAL`](https://redis.io/commands/eval) command.